I have taken a free account in Azure DevOps for practice and I am unable to see classic editor option in Azure Pipeline to build a code from Repos
enter image description here
please help me on this, do I need to change any type of settings?
I have created a Project with basic and tried on Agile as well but no use.
I tried creating different project, Organizations setting.
and when I am using Free trial Azure DevOps I am not getting all options in Azure Pipelines. I am getting only 3 options like 1. Pipeline, 2. Environments, and 3. Library.

Classic pipelines are legacy. Is there a specific reason you don't want to use YAML?

You can disable or enable creation of classic pipelines by toggling the option at the organization level or project level.
For example, to enable it at the organization level, navigate to your organization settings > select Settings > turn off Disable creation of classic build pipelines and Disable creation of classic release pipelines.

The feature turned on by default for organizations created after March 2023. This means new organizations will be, by default, YAML-only. For more details about the feature, you can refer this official blog: Disable creation of classic pipelines.
